# Error al descargar reporte utilizando JasperReports en Jakarta Server Faces

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, wildfly, reporte

Estoy trabajando en la actualización de un proyecto realizado en Java Server Faces (JSF) con jdk 8u22 a Jakarta Server Faces (JSF) con jdk 18, de Apache Tomcat 9 a Jboss Wildfly 27. He migrado también de PostgreSQL 9.3 a PostgreSQL 15

Tengo una página web donde el usuario rellena un formulario y de acuerdo a lo seleccionado se genera un reporte utilizando jasperReports y posteriormente se descarga de forma automática (en este caso en formato pdf). En la versión anterior del proyecto (utilizando jdk 8) se generaba correctamente y posteriormente se descargaba de forma automática. Sin embargo, en esta actualización no se descarga el fichero.

He debuggeado el código y el reporte se genera, pero nunca se llega a descargar. Les comparto los fragmentos de código.

Este el botón que realiza la petición al ManagedBean:

```
<p:commandButton title="PDF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-pdf"
                                     styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true"
                                     actionListener="#{reportsBean.print_rs4b_tipo1_PDF()}" update="form1">
</p:commandButton>
```

En el bean se ejecuta este fragmento de código:

```
public void print_rs4b_tipo1_PDF() throws JRException, IOException {
        java.util.Map<String, Object> params = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();
        asignatura_Rs4b_tipo1 = getAsignaturaByName();
        params.put("nombreasignatura", asignatura_Rs4b_tipo1.getAsignaturaId());
        String filename = "Modelo Rs-4-b-1";
        String jasperpath = URL + "rs4btipo1.jasper";
        reportUtil.PDF(params, jasperpath, filename);
}
```

Por último, se ejecuta esta función que es donde se procesa el reporte y posteriormente se indica la descarga del archivo PDF.

```
public void PDF(java.util.Map<String, Object> params, String jasperpath, String fileName) throws JRException, IOException, NullPointerException {
        try {
            if (params == null) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERROR: Debe seleccionar o introducir un valor", "Error"));
            }
            String relativeWebPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(jasperpath);
            File file = new File(relativeWebPath);
            Connection con = connection.getConnectionInstance("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SIGENU_EaD", "postgres", "postgres");
            String filename = file.getPath();
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, params, con);
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, stream);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERROR: Existen errores al generar el reporte", "Error"));
        }
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme con esta petición. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a @JasperdeVries por su respuesta. Te doy la solución completa.

Para resolver esta situación se puede utilizar ajax. Se puede utilizar el componente de descarga de Primefaces. Usando la clase `StreamedContent` de Primefaces, la secuencia del informe generado se puede obtener y luego enviar a la vista a través de `p:filedownloader`.

La vista se vería así:

```
<h:form id="form1">
                <p:growl id="messages" allowDismiss="true"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-3">
                        <p:outputLabel for="idSearch"
                                       styleClass="block"> Identificaci&oacute;n </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputMask
                                id="idSearch"
                                mask="99999999999"
                                requiredMessage="ERROR: Es necesario un valor para establecer la b&uacute;squeda"
                                validatorMessage="ERROR: Idemtificaci&oacute;n no v&aacute;lida"
                                placeholder="Identificaci&oacute;n" value="#{reportsBean.idEstudiante}"
                                required="true"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton title="PDF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-pdf"
                                         styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true" update="form1"
                                         actionListener="#{reportsBean.printCertCalifCursoAc('PDF')}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsBean.file}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton title="DOCX" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-word"
                                         styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true" update="form1"
                                         actionListener="#{reportsBean.printCertCalifCursoAc('DOCX')}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsBean.file}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton title="RTF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file"
                                         styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true" update="form1"
                                         actionListener="#{reportsBean.printCertCalifCursoAc('RTF')}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsBean.file}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden"
                       name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                       value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </h:form>
```

Luego, en el bean se preparan las bases para procesar el archivo, se define el objeto `StreamedContent` y con una función se envían los datos del informe al procesador de informes.

```
public void printCertCalifCursoAc(String type){
        Map<String, Object> params = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("id", idEstudiante);
        String fileName = "Certificado de Calificaciones de Curso Académico - " + idEstudiante + "." + type.toLowerCase();
        String jasperPath = URL + "ms19d.jasper";
        FileType fileType = FileType.valueOf(type);
        try {
            file = reportUtil.processReport(params, jasperPath, fileName, fileType);
        } catch (JRException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Por último se procesa el fichero, teniendo en cuenta el tipo de fichero que se va a procesar (PDF, RTF o DOCX en este caso). Y se envía el StreamContent al Bean para luego enviarse a la vista.

```
private StreamedContent getStreamedcontent(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
        SerializableSupplier<InputStream> supplier = () -> inputStream;
        StreamedContent streamedContent = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                .contentType("application/octet-stream")
                .name(fileName)
                .stream(supplier)
                .build();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return streamedContent;
    }

    public StreamedContent processReport(Map<String, Object> params, String jasperpath, String fileName, FileType fileType) throws IOException, JRException {
        if (params == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERROR: Debe seleccionar o introducir un valor", "Error"));
        }
        String relativeWebPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(jasperpath);
        File file = new File(relativeWebPath);
        Connection con = connection.getConnectionInstance("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SIGENU_EaD", "postgres", "postgres");
        String filename = file.getPath();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, params, con);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        switch (fileType) {
            case PDF -> JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, outputStream);
            case RTF -> {
                JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
                exporter.exportReport();
            }
            case DOCX -> {
                JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
                exporter.exportReport();
            }
        }
        return getStreamedcontent(outputStream, fileName);
    }
```